# C++ memory semantics and globals that are set at the start of a program

Tags: c++, multithreading

If I have one thread, the "main" thread, initialize a global variable and that thread later spawns some threads that access that variable, do I need to do any work, such as a call to std::atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_seq_cst), to guarantee that the variable appears initialized to the new threads? I suspect that the fact that the main thread creates the new threads establishes a "synchronized-with" relationship that is sufficient to prevent any races, but I'm not certain.

Here's some pseudocode for what I'm describing:

```
class MyApi {
public:
    static void init(Foo *foo) {
        MyApi::foo = foo;
    }

    static Foo* getSharedFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

private:
    static Foo* foo;
};

void main() {
    Foo* foo = new Foo();
    MyApi::init(foo);
    // Spawn threads that will call MyApi::getSharedFoo() and expect
    // to receive the same foo that is created above.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't have to do anything special. New threads see all memory changes up to the point where they were constructed.

Answer (score 0):

> 30.3.1.2 thread constructors
>
> [ ... ] template  explicit thread(F&& f,
>   Args&&... args);
>
> [ ... ]
>
> Synchronization: The completion of the invocation of the constructor
>   synchronizes with the beginning of the invocation of the copy of f.

This specifies that `f` sees everything that occurred prior to the construction of the `std::thread` object that spawned the thread.